# React: setState passed Update Function containing Map function not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am following a Todolist tutorial using React. In my App.js, I have (i) an internal state with a `todos` array containing `todo` objects and (ii) a `toggleComplete` handler for children components representing each `todo`. Upon event triggered by the child component, `toggleComplete` receives the child `id`,  finds the `todo` in `todos` with matching `id` and flips its completion boolean which results in a style change for that child.

The tutorial implements `toggleComplete` as the following which works:

```
  toggleComplete = function(id) {
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
        if(todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      }) 
    })
```

However, when I instead try to implement `toggleComplete` by passing `setState` an update function instead of an object, React does not re-render. Using console logs I see that the `map` and the `if` are executed. Following is the code:

```
  toggleComplete = function(id) {
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
      return {
        todos: prevState.todos.map( (todo) => {
          if(todo.id === id) {
            todo.completed = !todo.completed;
          }
          return todo;
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Update: By console.logging I see that the second approach is running map twice, which is why the style doesn't appear to change. Specifically, `toggleComplete` runs once but `this.setState` runs twice. However, the first approach only runs everything once. **Why is the second approach running twice?**

Comment: it happens when React does not aware of props changes and that's why it 's not re-rendering !